# Java random seed

Tags: java, random, seed

I have a java assignment I'd like some help with. There is a tester program that uses a random number seed and it's giving me problems coming up with the same result.

```
 boolean filled = true;
 while(filled)
     {
             int j = GRID_SIZE*GRID_SIZE;
             int k = random.nextInt(j);
             int l = k % GRID_SIZE;
             k = k/GRID_SIZE;
             while(grid[k][l] < 2)
             {
                     int newTile = random.nextInt(100);
                     if(newTile < 90) newTile = 2;
                     if(newTile >= 90) newTile = 4;
                     grid[k][l] = newTile;
                     filled = false;
             }
     }
}
```

The random object is passed in as a parameter to the class and has some set seed in the test file. When I run this method twice I get the following matrix. GRID_SIZE is a global variable.

```
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[2 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
```

But I should be getting

```
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 2 0 0]
[0 0 2 0]
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

EDIT: Updated the code and result. I was supposed to be using one number from 0-15 not two from 0-3. I'm still not getting the right result.

There is also global variable and random parameter passed in like this.

```
private final Random random;

public Board(int size, Random random) {
this.random = random;
...etc.
```

I don't know if that is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Why "should" you be getting that result? You should get the same result each time you run the code, if the seed is being set... but it's unclear why you think you should get a specific different result to the one you're getting.

Comment: A tester file is provided and it tells me what I should be getting.

Comment: Does it specify *how* you're meant to be getting that? There are any number of ways you *could* implement this which would be reasonable but could give different results for the same seed.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, two instances of `Random` initialized with the same seed will produce exactly the same pseudorandom series.  If you need it to be different each time then you will need to provide a different seed, i.e. a `long` current time-of-day value would suffice for the seed.

Comment: I am trying to get the exact same values as in the test case. It seems to not be using the same seed. I'll update with some more info with the random parameter.